# Set property value during FluentValidation in AbstractValidator<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, fluentvalidation

I have created an API endpoint using .net core Web API which is used to create a contract in my system. Before inserting the data I'm validating my properties using FluentValidation. There is a scenario, I'm getting a string as an input(i.e, `{center:"test center", group:"testGroup", company:"testCompany"}`) from the API endpoint(GUID is ignoring but if the string property values are valid, I've to set the GUID ([JsonIgnore] properties) against the string property values) and validate it in DB whether the strings are exists or not. If the strings(Center, Group, and Company) exist in DB I have to set Guids(CenterId, GroupId, and CompanyId) instead of strings property from DB. To be honest I don't have any idea to set the Property value using FluentValidation in AbstractValidator constructor. If anybody knows kindly share your inputs. FYI I have attached the tables schemas with data.
[image]

```
    public class Contract
    {
            [JsonIgnore]
            public Guid CenterId { get; set; }
            [JsonIgnore]
            public Guid? CompanyId { get; set; }
            [JsonIgnore]
            public Guid? GroupId { get; set; }

            public string Center { get; set; }

            public string Company { get; set; }

            public string Group { get; set; }
    }

    public class ContractValidator : AbstractValidator<Contract> {
        public ContractValidator(IUsersRepository usersRepository) {
            RuleFor(c => c.Company)
                .MustAsync((command, company) => usersRepository.Exists(command.Company))
                .When(c => c.Company != string.Empty)
                .WithMessage(command => $"Company does not exist");
             RuleFor(c => c.Center)
                .MustAsync((command, center) => usersRepository.Exists(command.Center))
                .When(c => c.Center!= string.Empty)
                .WithMessage(command => $"Center does not exist");
RuleFor(c => c.Group)
                .MustAsync((command, group) => usersRepository.Exists(command.Group))
                .When(c => c.Group!= string.Empty)
                .WithMessage(command => $"Group does not exist");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you want to use FluentValidation in the wrong way. In my opinion the validator MUST NOT change the model being validated. It is not validator's responsibility.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this functionality? Because When I pass inputs to the properties. It'll validate the string values in DB at first. After that again I have to get the Guid against the string value from DB for mapping the property value. So totally two times I need to hit the DB to validate these properties. Instead, once the string properties are validated in AbstractValidator<T>, the method will returns the Guid against string values. So that I can avoid one more DB hit. That's the reason I'm trying to do it.

Comment: Maybe you should populate identifiers manually and then validate your model without using the repository. In this case you need only one hit the DB.